# npm run build выдаёт ошибку

Tags: reactjs

Есть реакт проект. Пытаюсь сделать npm run build, но выдаётся ошибка:
static/css/main.0ecc99ac.css from Css Minimizer plugin
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ваш проект по команде `npm run start` вообще работает? Похоже у вас ошибка в коде. Где то вы хотите указать `value` чего то, что **undefined**

Comment: Да работает, локально открывается. Хотел захостить, но не получается, всё перепроверил вроде в коде нет ошибок.

Comment: Смотрите логи сборки, может там будет информация, где сборщик споткнулся. Т.к. ругается на css файл, я бы поковырял все что связано с css и сборщиком css, если кастомизировано

Comment: Ок, спасибо, еще поковыряюсь